# toggle a css color on hover

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a highlight color to a class like this

```js
$(".common_box").hover(function(){
    $(".common_box").addClass("hover_me");
});
```

This works but why doesnt this

```js
$(".common_box").hover(function(){
    $(".common_box").toggleClass("hover_me");
});
```

When i hover over this nothing happens

Is there no unhover to put to remove the class hover_me when they move away from the hover

Comment: Though the answer below works, also consider using pure CSS and `:hover`, if IE6 isn't a consideration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's currently a bug in some situations where the mouse enter/leave events are firing twice, so it *is* working, but it's double toggling each in/out, so no net effect...for now, to be safe:

```
$(".common_box").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("hover_me");
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass("hover_me");
});
```

This is a bug (I *believe*) because of the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) changes to support [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), which is causing some unwanted side-effects, you can be explicit like above to be 100% safe, so if each handler runs multiple times, at least for your purposes, it's alright.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  $(".common_box").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hover_me");
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("hover_me");
  });
```

Comment: You want to stick with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` (what `.hover()`'s 2 function arguments map to) here, as they won't be fired when entering/leaving child elements within .common_box.