# How to align a button just below a horizontal navigation menu?

Tags: html, css

How to align a button that is centered middle just below a horizontal navigation menu?
I do not want to overlap the menu list items with the button and the button should be spaced and placed accordingly when the menu expands.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Welcome</title>
<style type="text/css">
    * {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

body {
    background-color:#f7f0f0;
    font-family:Verdana;
    padding:50px;   /*all four paddings are 50px*/
}

h1 {
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom:2px solid #666;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

ul#mainmenu,ul.sub1,ul.sub2,ul.sub3,ul.sub4,ul.sub5 {
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size:15px;
}

ul#mainmenu {
    padding-top:10px;
}

ul#mainmenu li{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:350px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-right:3px;   /*renders a right margin of 5 pixels around the list items */
}

ul#mainmenu a {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    line-height:25px;   /*gives a vertical centering*/
    width:350px;    /*same as the width of the list items*/
    height:25px;
    background:linear-gradient(to right,#bdc2ed,white,#bdc2ed); /*create a color gradient to the right*/
    border-radius:5px;
    /*outline:1px solid red;*/  /*takes up the space outside of the elements's container (i.e. in this case the outside of the list items*/
}

ul#mainmenu .sub1 li {
    margin-top:2px;
}

ul#mainmenu .sub1 a {
    border:1px solid green; /*takes up the space outside of the content itself i.e. the anchor tags . That's where the border radius comes into the picture*/
}

ul#mainmenu .sub2 li,.sub3 li,.sub4 li,.sub5 li {
    margin-left:20px;
}

ul#mainmenu li:hover > a {
    text-transform:uppercase; /*select and style every <a> element where the the par */
    background:linear-gradient(to right,blue,white,blue);
    border:1px solid black;
}

ul#mainmenu li:hover a:hover {
    background:linear-gradient(to right,#718ce5,white,#718ce5);
}

ul#mainmenu ul.sub1 {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:26px;
    left:0px;
}

ul#mainmenu ul.sub2 {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:-2px;
    left:335px;
}

ul#mainmenu ul.sub3 {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:-2px;
    left:335px;
}

ul#mainmenu ul.sub4 {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:-2px;
    left:335px;
}

ul#mainmenu ul.sub5 {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:-2px;
    left:335px;
}

ul#mainmenu li:hover ul.sub1 
{
    display:block;
}

ul#mainmenu ul.sub1 li:hover ul.sub2
{
    display:block;
}

ul#mainmenu ul.sub2 li:hover ul.sub3
{
    display:block;
}

ul#mainmenu ul.sub2  li#submenu_shirts:hover ul.sub4
{
    display:block;
}

ul#mainmenu ul.sub1 li#submenu_shoes:hover ul.sub5
{
    display:block;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("button").click(function () {
            $("ul#mainmenu li:first").hide(500);
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome</h1>
<div>
<form action="" >
<ul id="mainmenu">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Products</a>
    <ul class="sub1">
        <li><a href="#">Clothing</a>
            <ul class="sub2">
                <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a>
                    <ul class="sub3">
                            <li><a href="#">Polo</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">V-Neck</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Henley</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="submenu_shirts"><a href="#">Shirts</a>
                    <ul class="sub4">
                            <li><a href="#">Half-Sleeve</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Full-Sleeve</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Jeans</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Trousers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="submenu_shoes"><a href="#">Shoes</a>
            <ul class="sub5">
                <li><a href="#">Sports-Shoes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Formal-Shoes</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>

<div>
<input type="submit" value="Post"/>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rplute/a8xVJ/1/).

My solution uses jQuery. I use the hover selector with a toggle. I also centered the menu (not sure if you wanted that or not ~ if not, uncomment the float:left for the unordered list). It would normally push the input button down, but the problem is that the embedded unordered list has an absolute position for all the list items. This overrides the button input, which has a relative position. So I just instead accounted for the position of the button on the hover product list item as that is the only one that seems to cause the problem. Thus, this solution should only be used specifically for the problem listed above.

```
$("li.products").hover(function(){
    $( ".btn" ).css( "top", "60px" );
}, function(){
    $( ".btn" ).css( "top", "0px" );
});
```

Other good resources for hover jQuery selector:

1.) jQuery API docs - http://api.jquery.com/hover/

2.) Stack Overflow Question - [toggle a css color on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747956/toggle-a-css-color-on-hover)

Comment: It's a good alternate solution and very clearly explained too.

Answer (score 0):

Change the widht values as following...

```
ul#mainmenu li{
    width:250px;


ul#mainmenu a {
    width:250px;
```

REPLACE:

OLD:

```
<form action="" >
<ul id="mainmenu">
```

NEW:

```
<form action="" >
<ul id="mainmenu" style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }

    body {
        background-color:#f7f0f0;
        font-family:Verdana;
        padding:50px;   /*all four paddings are 50px*/
    }

    h1 {
        text-align:center;
        border-bottom:2px solid #666;
        padding-bottom:10px;
    }

    ul#mainmenu,ul.sub1,ul.sub2,ul.sub3,ul.sub4,ul.sub5 {
        list-style-type:none;
        font-size:15px;
    }

    ul#mainmenu {
        padding-top:10px;
    }

    ul#mainmenu li{
        float:left;
        position:relative;
        width:250px;
        text-align:center;
        margin-right:3px;   /*renders a right margin of 5 pixels around the list items */
    }

    ul#mainmenu a {
        text-decoration:none;
        display:block;
        line-height:25px;   /*gives a vertical centering*/
        width:250px;    /*same as the width of the list items*/
        height:25px;
        background:linear-gradient(to right,#bdc2ed,white,#bdc2ed); /*create a color gradient to the right*/
        border-radius:5px;
        /*outline:1px solid red;*/  /*takes up the space outside of the elements's container (i.e. in this case the outside of the list items*/
    }

    ul#mainmenu .sub1 li {
        margin-top:2px;
    }

    ul#mainmenu .sub1 a {
        border:1px solid green; /*takes up the space outside of the content itself i.e. the anchor tags . That's where the border radius comes into the picture*/
    }

    ul#mainmenu .sub2 li,.sub3 li,.sub4 li,.sub5 li {
        margin-left:20px;
    }

    ul#mainmenu li:hover > a {
        text-transform:uppercase; /*select and style every <a> element where the the par */
        background:linear-gradient(to right,blue,white,blue);
        border:1px solid black;
    }

    ul#mainmenu li:hover a:hover {
        background:linear-gradient(to right,#718ce5,white,#718ce5);
    }

    ul#mainmenu ul.sub1 {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        top:26px;
        left:0px;
    }

    ul#mainmenu ul.sub2 {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        top:-2px;
        left:335px;
    }

    ul#mainmenu ul.sub3 {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        top:-2px;
        left:335px;
    }

    ul#mainmenu ul.sub4 {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        top:-2px;
        left:335px;
    }

    ul#mainmenu ul.sub5 {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        top:-2px;
        left:335px;
    }

    ul#mainmenu li:hover ul.sub1 
    {
        display:block;
    }

    ul#mainmenu ul.sub1 li:hover ul.sub2
    {
        display:block;
    }

    ul#mainmenu ul.sub2 li:hover ul.sub3
    {
        display:block;
    }

    ul#mainmenu ul.sub2  li#submenu_shirts:hover ul.sub4
    {
        display:block;
    }

    ul#mainmenu ul.sub1 li#submenu_shoes:hover ul.sub5
    {
        display:block;
    }

    .button {
        width:800px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("button").click(function () {
                $("ul#mainmenu li:first").hide(500);
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div>
    <form action="" >
    <ul id="mainmenu" style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul class="sub1">
            <li><a href="#">Clothing</a>
                <ul class="sub2">
                    <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a>
                        <ul class="sub3">
                                <li><a href="#">Polo</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">V-Neck</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Henley</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="submenu_shirts"><a href="#">Shirts</a>
                        <ul class="sub4">
                                <li><a href="#">Half-Sleeve</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Full-Sleeve</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Jeans</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Trousers</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="submenu_shoes"><a href="#">Shoes</a>
                <ul class="sub5">
                    <li><a href="#">Sports-Shoes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Formal-Shoes</a></li> 
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </form>
</div>

<div>
<input type="submit" value="Post"/>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```